# On the calculation of curve integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $\vec{n}$ be the out of unit normal vector on the curve $\varGamma$,and the $\varGamma:x^2+y^2=R^2$.define$$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$Calculate$$\oint_{\varGamma}\dfrac{\partial\ln r}{\partial{\vec{n}}}\mathrm{d}s.$$
I made the following attempts,Known that $\vec{n}=(\dfrac{x}{R},\dfrac{y}{R})$.So$$\dfrac{\partial\ln r}{\partial{\vec{n}}}=\dfrac{\partial\ln r}{\partial{x}}\cdot\dfrac{x}{R}+\dfrac{\partial\ln r}{\partial{y}}\cdot\dfrac{y}{R}$$
But I don't understand why
$$\dfrac{\partial\ln r}{\partial\vec{n}}=\dfrac{d\ln r}{d r}$$
Can you explain it to me, thank you.

Comment: Note the normal vector in this case is $\vec{r}$. So when you are finding the rate of change of $f(r) = \ln r$ in the direction of the unit normal, it means you are finding the rate of change of $f(r)$ in the direction of $\vec{r}$. Does that explain?

Comment: @Math Lover Thank you,but why the normal vector is$\vec{r}$ not $\vec{n}$?

Comment: $\vec{n}$ is a general notation for a unit normal vector. For a circle centered at the origin, an outward normal vector will be from the origin pointing out radially. So the normal vector is $\vec{r} = x \hat{i} + y \hat{j}$ where $(x, y)$ is on the circle. When it comes to unit normal it can be written as $\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$. But the point you should focus on is that you are trying to find rate of change of $f(r)$ in the direction of $\vec{n}$ which is radially outward vector.

Comment: @Math Lover I think I know what you mean. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Math Lover it means that the $\vec{n}=\frac{\vec{r}}{r}$ in this case?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Math Lover Can you help me with this problem, thank you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987320/how-to-prove-the-following-inequality-with-trigonometric-function

Answer (score 1):

Note that $R$ belongs to $\Gamma$.

At first the function $\frac{\partial \ln r}{\partial \vec n}$ is considered independently of $\Gamma$.

Now, interpreting $\frac{\partial \ln r}{\partial \vec n}$ as the derivative of $\ln r$ in the direction of $\vec n = \left( \frac x{\color{blue}{r}}\:\: \frac y{\color{blue}{r}} \right)$ you get

\begin{eqnarray*} \frac{\partial \ln r}{\partial \vec n}
& = & \frac 12 \left(\frac{\partial \ln (x^2+y^2)}{\partial x}\cdot\frac xr + \frac{\partial \ln (x^2+y^2)}{\partial y}\cdot\frac yr  \right) \\
& = & \frac 12 \left(\frac {2x}{r^2}\cdot\frac xr + \frac {2y}{r^2}\cdot\frac yr\right) \\
& = & \frac 1r\\
& = & \frac{d\ln r}{dr}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: OK, thank you. It seems that we need to work it out rather than get it directly...

Comment: You are welcome.