# How to prove the following inequality with trigonometric function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

For any non-zero real number $x_1$, $x_2$,$$\left|x_1\sin{\frac{1}{x_1}}-x_2\sin{\frac{1}{x_2}}\right|\leq2\sqrt{|x_1-x_2|}.$$
I tried the following,
$$\begin{array}{rl}\left|x_2\sin\frac{1}{x_2}-x_1\sin\frac{1}{x_1}\right|&\leq 
\left|x_2\sin\frac{1}{x_2}-x_1\sin\frac{1}{x_2}\right|+\left|x_1\sin\frac{1}{x_2}-x_1\sin\frac{1}{x_1}\right|\\ 
&\leq |x_2-x_1|+|x_1|\left|\frac{1}{x_2}-\frac{1}{x_1}\right|\\ 
&=\frac{1+|x_2|}{|x_2|}|x_2-x_1|\\ 
\end{array}$$
But I don't know how to go on...

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523297/how-to-prove-this-inequality-bigx-sin-frac1x-y-sin-frac1y-big2

Comment: @Math Lover well thank you,I have a look at it. It seems that there is no strict proof.btw,how do you find these posts?

Comment: Nothing fancy, I just noticed it on the right, under section _Linked_

Comment: @Math Lover I feel these answers are not very beautiful

Comment: Yes you may be right but also consider this - the question had a bounty on it which would usually attract higher attention to it. So may be there is no better solution to it.

Comment: @MathLover The bounty was given by Community so it need not have a bounty set up by asker

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore you are missing the point. It does not matter who awarded the bounty. The bounty is to get more attention to the question.